# Converting SVG to PNG without changing the font

Tags: javascript, node.js, svg, imagemagick, graphicsmagick

I'm trying to make a simple app which takes text from users and edit the text in svg file (generated from illustrator) and sends back to the user with the final result.

I'm able to change the SVG file text in javascript but I'm having problems with converting it to png. When I do, it changes to a different roboto like font.

Here is my svg

```
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 2248.1 769.99">
    <defs>
        <style>
            .cls-1{
                font-size:350px;
                font-family:Granger-Regular, Granger;
            }
        </style>
    </defs>
    <title>test</title>
    <text class="cls-1" x="50%" y ="50%" >
        <tspan  text-anchor="middle">Example</tspan>
        <tspan  text-anchor="middle" x="50%" y ="50%" dy="300">SVG</tspan>
    </text>
</svg>
```

Here is the code I'm using to convert,

```
var fs = require('fs')
  , gm = require('gm');

gm('./../src/images/test.svg')
    .write('./../src/images/test.png', function (err) {
        //console.log(err)
        if (!err) console.log('done');
    });
```

Svg looks something like this,

[image]

But when I convert it looks like this,
[image]

So how can I fix it? :(

Comment: SVG perhaps has the font imbedded. But your OS may not have the same font. Be sure you install the same font into your system.

Comment: The font is installed on my local mac os. But when I run the convert function through  cloud functions I get that font issue. Tried adding  @font-face {font-family: Granger-Regular; src: url('./../fonts/Granger-Regular.ttf');} but it's not working.

Comment: @fmw42 forgot to mention. please read the above comment

Comment: The issue may be the cloud function not finding your font by name.  Sorry I do not know much about cloud tools. Also, there are several SVG renderers. ImageMagick can use its default internal MSVG/XML, or you can install the RSVG delegate into ImageMagick or you can install Inkscape on your system and ImageMagick will use that. They are listed in order of best results. You can see which is used in the ImageMagick command `convert -list format` and look at the line for SVG. But I see you are using GM not IM, so I do not know what it does.

Comment: I downloaded your svg file and installed the granger-regular ttf font on my Mac and ran `convert test.svg test.png` and it did not use the granger font. So perhaps something is not correct in your SVG file specification of the font. I am not an expert on SVG files. So I am not sure I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar thing those days, where the svg included arabic typography, which is not just written from right to left, but also has a lot of ligatures. I started out using `imagemagick`. To make that use the right font, the font needs to be installed on the the system, where the conversion should take place, in our case it was the webserver, where we couldn't install the font. But on a local environment I noticed that `imagemagick` wasn't able to deal with the text-direction and ligatures well, so we needed to find another solution. The final winner was the [apache batik project](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/), which is implemented in java. We were lucky in this case since a `shell_exec('java -jar …')` was possible from the `php` side. If you go into the examples/tests Directory of the Project, you can find graphics which are using external fonts, included via the `@fontface {}` directive. When using batik, what is doing a great job, just keep in mind that **all paths needs to relative to svg itself**.

Answer (score 0):

So this was my problem too. Based on my research i made a working POC that address this problem statement. Please go through the readme to understand the project itself.

Github: https://github.com/nirus/SVG-PNG-Convert

I have compiled all the problems that i faced with and **solution that solved it**. Give it try !